# python: How to input a string and use it as query match elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to code a simple `python` script which should ask for a string to be inserted by shell and use it as "match string" in a match query. I post here the script so the problem can be better understandable.

```
client = Elasticsearch()

query_string = raw_input("Enter your query string: ")
print(query_string)

s = Search(using=client, index="enron_test"
    .query("match", message_body=query_string))

response = s.execute()
```

Actually, I should get all the `json` documents (each represents an email) which contain the string "query_string" in the `message_body` field.

The problem is that when I run the script, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'`.
I'm a newbie in `Elasticsearch`, where am I wrong? Or maybe this thing I'm trying to do is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are calling the query method on the string "enrox_test".

I dont know what library you are using so I cant check the syntax. But I think you are missing something between "enron_text" and ".query(..."

Comment: I'm using this libraries `from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch  and from elasticsearch_dsl import Search`

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis after "enron-text". You can check out one of the search example here for the syntax of the search request here : https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If this solves the problem, please do close the question and mark as the answer. It can help someone else with a similar error :)